# How to format a Date in windows phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm a little stuck trying to display a timespan data using the StringFormat property. I'm using the following code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration, StringFormat='Time: {0:HH.mm}'}" FontSize="12" />
```

When I run my App to test it, after to click on a button to retrieve some data (in which a timespan value is include), the App simply gets frozen.

However, If I don't use the string format property, the data is displayed OK in the format of:
**00:03:49.4590000**

The above output is the one I wanna displayed either as 00:03:49 (HH:mm:ss) or 03:49 (mm:ss)

Also, I found this code which suppously do the same:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration, StringFormat=\{0\:N0\}}" FontSize="12" />
```

But, the resut is the same. The App gets frozen

Does anyone have a good example how to use the string format property to dislplay a TimeSpan value?
Or do I miss something the the above code?

Regards!

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt}}" />

Comment: Thanks for your help john. However, the data I'm trying to format is a TimeSpan not a date

Comment: just remove the MM/dd/yyy stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind TimeSpan like this, textblock will display like 02:23(2 hours and 23 minutes):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding time, StringFormat='{}{0:hh\\:mm}'}"/>
```

also you can convert your TimeSpan to DateTime, and bind it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding time, StringFormat='{}{0:HH:mm}'}"/>
```

Comment: The first code worked for me. In the second one the App gets frozen as describe in the original past. Thanks so much Chris